# RewriteRule splits parameter's last character

Tags: php, .htaccess

Here I am trying to rewrite parameters in .htaccess and make last parameter optional:

```bash
RewriteRule ^produktas/([0-9a-zA-Z_-]+)/?([0-9a-zA-Z_-]+) /produktas?slug=$1&var=$2 [NC,L]
```

So if I would type `http://site.lt/produktas/the-glass`, then I expect actually to get `http://site.lt/produktas?slug=the-glass`, but second parameter `var` I expect to be empty. But when I run it I get my first parameter spit and my `$_GET` variable looks like this:

```bash
Array ( [slug] => the-glas [var] => s )
```

How can I get first parameter full and second empty if I type only one parameter like this:
`http://site.lt/produktas/the-glass` ?

Comment: For clarity, `/?` makes only the slash optional, but not the capture group that follows it. Anubhava's answer correctly moves the slash inside the grouping, accounts for various edge cases, and condenses the character classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex pattern is not correct due to quantifier `+` used and an optional `/` between.

You may use this rule:

```bash
RewriteRule ^produktas/([\w-]+)(?:/([\w-]+))?/?$ produktas?slug=$1&var=$2 [NC,L,QSA]
```

Comment: Thank you. This works, just without dollar sign ```^produktas/([\w-]+)(?:/([\w-]+))?/?```, because before I removed ```.php``` from url.

Comment: Just now realized, that this works only on localhost, when url is ```http://site/produktas/the-glass```, but when try the same on hosting using ```http://site.lt/produktas/the-glass```, then page is not found.

Comment: That should not make a difference unless you have `produktas` inside a sub directory.